# Partial Differential Equation and Cusps

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $u_{xx}-Xu_{tt}=0$ show that the characteristics have cusps on $x=0$.
I'm not sure what is meant by cusps, what is the formal definition? The term has not been defined, may someone please elaborate?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Which texts are you reading?

Comment: Step 1: find the characteristics. A cusp is a point where a directional derivative does not exist

Comment: Geometrically, cusps are often non-smooth portions of a curve. For example, the vertex at the origin for y=|x|. The derivative doesn't exist because the pertinent limit is 1 from the right and -1 one from the left. More generally, a multivariable function will have cusps where the Partial Derivatives don't exist for various reasons.